# How can I sanitise input for a hash converter in PHP?

Tags: php, md5, sha1, sanitize, rainbowtable

I have made a website that generates hashes from users inputting plain text, a user can enter a word/ phrase and select from MD5 or SHA1 (or both). The site then takes this input and converts it into MD5 & SHA1 and stores it in a database, then returns it to the user. Users can also enter hashes into a search bar and if the database has the hash it will return the original word, the aim is to generate crowd-sourced hash tables whilst providing a benefit to users. I have got the main functionality working but I have a dilemma about what I should sanitize, I want users to be able to input special characters as it will improve the chances of the search function returning a result, any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: -1 for creating this service.

Comment: So long as you're MD5'ing or SHA1'ing the input when converting *to* a hash, nothing should need sanitising, right? And when searching for an existing hash, this shouldn't contain special characters anyway, so this *should* be sanitised. I've also retagged your question. This is called a [tag:rainbowtable], not a [tag:hashtable] - that's something different.

Comment: @WasimAbu-Nassar it is my first programming project, what is your problem?

Comment: Rainbow tables are used for breaking passwords... that's @WasimAbu-Nassar 's problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to sanitise anything if it's just going to be hashed, since hashing functions are generally not vulnerable to injection attacks.

You should, of course, sanitise all your database inputs (for both insertion and searching). However, unless you're using an antiquated database API that doesn't support parameterised queries (e.g. the `mysql_*` functions; avoid these) this will be done automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason for your application to sanitize *anything*.  All you're doing with your users' input is feeding it to a cryptographic hash function, and those functions will happily accept any byte sequences.

Of course, if you're displaying the input string on the result page, you should escape it with [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) before embedding it in HTML code.  Similarly, if you're including it as a parameter in a URL you should escape it with [urlencode()](http://php.net/urlencode), and if you're storing it in an SQL database, you should escape it with the appropriate escaping function for your database driver (e.g. [mysqli::escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)), or just use [prepared SQL statements with placeholders](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Also note that cryptographic hash functions operate on byte strings, not on character strings.  This means that, especially for text containing non-ASCII characters, the hash value will depend on the [character encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php) used to encode it into bytes.  For Unicode text, it may also depend on the [normalization form](http://php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php) used.  UTF-8 (with normalization form C or D, or just whatever the user's browser sends) may be a reasonably common choice these days, but if you want to be helpful, you may want to offer your users a choice of different encodings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think @Danny Beckett's suggestion is a viable option, if I convert the strings into MD5 or SHA1 before they are inserted in the database I assume there will be no vulnerability. Although I will look into the htmlspecialchars() for embedding it into the HTML code,

Thanks